# Does ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco model learn anything at all?

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, loss-function, convergence

I trained my dataset with "ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco" until 40k steps and its loss function still turn around 4. My dataset includes 500 images with 100 test images  and each images has 750 * 300 resolution. what can I do with this high degree of model intelligence!? with "faster rcnn incepteion v2 model" I had loss function arround 0.02 on this data set. whats wrong with "ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco"? Does this model learn anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

did you modified well the ssd_mobilenet foncig file ? you have to specify the number classes to detect, then the number picture in test/eval folder...

Comment: yes. I determined the number of classes and path of tfrecords as well. Also i reduced the batch size to 6 because of low memory. I think  i should select  a bigger batch size in ssd model in order that ssd reduce the loss properly.

Comment: i don't thinl batch size deal with it it just say how many picture took in same time.... how many memory do you have ? what version of python ? and tensorflow ? how do you install it ?